# How to add attributes to HTML tags when I use Emmet?

Tags: html, tags, sublimetext, emmet

I use Sublime Text and Emmet plug-in. Various tags do not include all the attributes automatically when I use Emmet, so I have to put them manually. For example the input tags have only "type" attribute when I enter "input" and press "Tab".

```
<input type="text">
```

but I want this for example

```
<input type="text" name="" id="">
```

How can I edit whichever attributes I want to see in a tag? I tried to find a solution on YouTube and through Google search but was not successful.

Comment: If the answer helped, please mark it as solved by clicking the checkmark next to it. This will help others finding the answer quicker.

Answer (score 8):

The Emmet syntax is modelled after CSS selectors, so in order to add attributes (or properties), you need pass them in square brackets.

**Example**

Input:

`input#first_name[type=text][name=first_name]`

Output:

```html
<input type="text" id="first_name" name="first_name">
```

As for your example, you would need to type this:

`input[type=text][name]#`

This breaks down as follows:

1. `input` - name of the tag
2. `type` attribute with the value of `text`
3. `name` attribute without value
4. empty `id` attribute

Edit:

The `type` attribute stands for `:`, so you could write this as:

`input:text[name]#`